# Serving private media files from S3 to single page React App (Django DRF backend)

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have set up an S3 bucket on AWS where I upload my sensitive ‘media’ files from my Django DRF + React app. The files are not public. I use boto3 and Django-storages for that and the upload process works fine. I can also download the files for report generation from backend to return PDF response.

I would now like to display those files one by one from frontend. It seems like I now have two options:

- Create a route in Django API/urls to handle media requests and point the app to the media directory. This way, the AWS login is handled by the backend server. This seems to beat the point of using a CDN as all media requests would go via the backend server?
- Incorporate login credentials to React front end. This seems insecure.

What would be the recommended way to achieve this? I can’t seem to find the required information.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: I ended up creating a django URL (as per bullet point 1 in the post). If anyone has better suggestions let me know.

Comment: Would you be interested in an answer on an effective sample to demonstrate how Presigned URLs would work?